# Simple ODE problem in a 1964 paper of Peter Lax

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The paper "*Development of singularities of solutions of the nonlinear hyperbolic partial differential equation" by Peter D.Lax (1964). It starts with a simple theorem about ODEs.

Theorem: Let $z(t)$ be the solution of the initial value problem $$dz/dt =a(t)z^2,\ \ \ z(0)=m$$
in the interval $(0,T)$. Suppose that the function $a(t)$ satisfies the inequality
$$0<A<a(t),\ \ \ \ \ \ 0\leq t\leq T,$$
and suppose that $m$ is positive;

then
$$T<(mA)^{-1}$$

the proof of Lax following

Let $z_0(t)$ be the solution of the comparision equation
$$dz_0/dt=Az_0^2,\ \ \ z_0(0)=m.$$

Since A is lower bound for $a(t)$, it follows easily that $z_0(t)$ is lower bound for $z(t)$ for all positive t.

Since $z_0=m/(1-mAt)\rightarrow \infty\ \ at\ \ t=(mA)^{-1}$, it follows that $z(t)$ cannot exist beyond this time. $Q.E.D$

I try to verify "Since A is lower bound for $a(t)$, it follows easily that $z_0(t)$ is lower bound for $z(t)$ for all positive t." in this way.

To prove this, I think a following lemma.

(My lemma) let $g:[0,T)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which are following;

i) $g(0)\geq 0$;
ii) $g'(0)>0$;  i.e. $\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists \delta>0$  s.t  $0<t<\delta$ imply $|\frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t}-g'(0)|<\epsilon$

then $\exists T^*\in (0,T)$   s.t   $g(t)\geq 0\ \ for\  t \in [0,T^*)$

proof) From my assumption, let $\epsilon= g'(0)/2$ then exist $\delta>0$ s.t $t\in(0,\delta)$
$$|\frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t}-g'(0)|<g'(0)/2$$

therefore $$g'(0)/2<[g(t)-g(0)]/t<3g'(0)/2\ \ \ for \ t \in (0,\delta)$$
$$g(t)>g'(0)t/2+g(0)>0\ \ for\ t\in(0,\delta)$$
because $g(0)\geq 0$, $g(t)\geq0\ \ \ \ for\ \ \ t \in [0,\delta)$. let $\delta= T*$ then proof is done.

now prove "Since A is lower bound for $a(t)$, it follows easily that $z_0(t)$ is lower bound for $z(t)$ for all positive t."

claim) let $z(t),z_0(t)$ satisfy above suggestion then  $z_0(t)\leq z(t)$ for $t \in [0,T)$.

(my proof) let $g(t)=z(t)-z_0(t)$ for $t \in [0,T) $
then $g(0)=m-m=0, g'(0)=(a(0)-A)m^2>0$
therefore $g(t)$ satisfy the suggestion of my lemma.
therefore $\exists T^*\in (0,T)$ s.t $t \in [0,T^*)$ imply $g(t)\geq 0$.

actually, $g(t)>0$ for $t\in(0,T^*)$. therefore $z(t)\geq z_0(t)$ for  $t \in [0,T^*)$,
$z(t)> z_0(t)$  for $t\in(0,T^*)$.

Now for contradiction, suppose there exist $T_p \in [T^*,T)$ s.t $z_0(T_p)>z(T_p)$; i.e $g(T_p)<0$.

Then there exist $T_1\in [T^*,T_p)$ s.t
i)$g(T_1)=0$;
ii)$g(t)>0 $ for $t\in (0,T_1)$
iii)$\exists \eta>0$ s.t $g(t)<0$ for $t\in(T_1,T_1+\eta)$

i.e) there exist $T_1$ which $g(t)$ first pass through from positive value to negative value.

then we can find contradiction, at $t=T_1$, $g'(T_1)=a(T_1)z(T_1)^2-A z_0(T_1)^2=(a(T_1)-A)z_0(T_1)^2>0 $ note that $z_0(T_1)= m/(1-mAt)>0$

by my lemma,there exist $T^{**}\in (T_1,T)$ s.t $t\in [T_1,T^{**})$ imply $g(t)\geq 0$;

therefore $z(t)-z_0(t)=g(t)\geq 0 \ \ \forall t\in [0,T)$. $z_0 is lower bound of z.$

this is my proof,

but I think there are some errors in my proof.

first, z is the solution for $dz/dt=a(t)z^2, \ \ \ z(0)=m$ in $(0,T)$ but I use $z'(0)-z_0'(0)>0$ for my proof, however $z'$ is not define for $t=0$

second, I use "there exist $T_1$ which $g(t)$ first pass through from positive value to negative value.", but actually, I don't know how to clarify this sentence.

If you have some idea to clarify my proof,or If you have better idea to prove "Since A is lower bound for $a(t)$, it follows easily that $z_0(t)$ is lower bound for $z(t)$ for all positive t.",

please give me some help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$z(t)$ by assumption is a solution of the ODE on $(0,T)$. By the uniqueness theorem, it can not cross the zero axis, as the zero function is already a solution.

With that you get the claim much easier by using the transformation $u=-z^{-1}$ which makes the ODE much simpler. You get
$$
u'=z^{-2}z'=a(t)>A\implies u(t)-u(0)=\int_0^ta(s)ds>At.
$$

---

The more general statement for solution bounds usually goes something like:

> *If $f(t,z)\ge g(t,z)$ and $z_0$ is a solution of $z_0'(t)=g(t,z_0(t))$, then $z(t)\ge z_0(t)$ for $t>0$ for any solution of $z'(t)=f(t,z(t))$ with $z(0)\ge z_0(0)$.* (If necessary, this claim can be restricted to $t\in[0,T]$ when the first inequality is valid only on that time interval.)

Comment: Actually, to define $u=z^{-1}$,  $z(t)\neq 0 $ for $t\in [0,T)$. surely, if we assume $\exists t \in(0,T)$ s.t $z(t)=0$ then by mean value theorem $(z(t)-z(0))/t=z'(c)=a(t)z(c)^2$ for some $c \in (0,t)$ but this is contradiction because $(z(t)-z(0))/t=-m/t<0$ but, $a(t)z(c)^2 \geq 0$. But to use mean value theorem, the continuity of z on [0,t] should be guaranteed. how we can clarify the continuity of z at t=0 in this system?

Comment: This only becomes a problem when $a(t)$ is not continuous. Otherwise you have uniqueness and a zero solution. Note also that a solution to an ODE (with emphasis on the "ordinary") is by definition continuously differentiable, thus also continuous.

Comment: Thank you your clear answer. In paper, actually, any other suggestion of a(t) is not given, so there were many limitations when trying to prove this theorem. Acutally, in common case, I think a(t) is given as continuous function. so for now, I will accept this theorem as being true for the continuous function a(t).

Comment: We know that $z(t)$ can only be increasing from $z(0)=m>0$, so is positive on $(0,T)$. Then the transformation to $u$ works and you get the solution formula $$z(t)=\frac{m}{1-m\int_0^t a(s)\,ds}.$$ So the only restriction is that the integral of $a$ has to exist. Now it is easy to see that $m\int_0^t a(s)\,ds<1$ on $(0,T)$ implies $mAT<1$.

Comment: But actually, the existance of integral of a is not imply the uniqueness of solution. Lax actually assume only local existence of solution, I think there isn't guarantee z(t) has the form you suggested.

Comment: No, uniqueness is only needed to prove positivity without any mention of monotonicity. The solution formula does not have any singularities except the one under examination, so uniqueness follows directly from its calculation.

Comment: oh! thank you, I understand what you mean. actually if a is integrable, then this ode is solved directly, and in (0,T), as you said the singularity is not occur thanks to A. therefore uniqueness is guaranteed actually.